# Checking if a point is inside the cube (using matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, octave

Let me clarify my question with a question:

Assume that I have a big cube = 100*100*100 and there are little cubes inside the big cube which construct big cube and their sizes are = 10*10*10. (I have 1000 little cubes inside the big cube) Now, I need to check, in which cube my point (2,2,2) exists. Answer is for sure 1st cube for this question. Then after finding the cube, I will hold the number of points that each cube consists.

My attempt: At first I thought if I compare my point with 8 corners it would be enough. I though that my point's coordinates must be greater then the 4 corners of the cube, and less then the remaining 4 corners of the cube and then I was going to iteratively increment the coordinates of the corner point to check for the other cubes. However, now I see that I am wrong.

What would be the best suiting algorithm for this problem?

Regards,
Amadeus

note: I am using MATLAB, therefore if there are any built-in functions for this purpose, I can use them also.

Comment: Divide the coordinates by 10 and that's your answer (after rounding down). If you're not looking for this, then how are you naming the small cubes?

Comment: @irrelephant: I suggest you add that as an answer.

Comment: @irrelephant first of all, it was just an example, I am not sure which size would be better for my little cubes. Therefore I am planning to write a parametric code assuming that each cube's edge length = l. But anyways according to what you say, then if I divide my coordinates by l, it will be enough.But unfortunately I did not understand it. For example if my point is (8,18,9), how do you find the cube that contains this point? do you say it is cube(0,1,0)?Ordering of the cubes does not matter.What I need is every cubes location in the big cube. Because I will construct a map with that later.

Comment: if your big cube is 100*100*100, make a new cube that is 10*10*10 of zeros which represents all the small cubes. now for each point (i, j, k), increment the (i//10, j//10, k//10) position of the 10*10*10 cube.

Comment: @robertking that is a quite good way of representation. What about finding the cubes that my points belong to?

Comment: @irrelephant wow I got it now. I guess in the beginning I did not want to believe that such an easy solution could fit. Thank you so much!

Comment: You have forgotten to say how are your cubes oriented? Along axes or not? If yes, than the answer of irrelephant is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a cube N*N*N. And you create small cubes of dimension n*n*n.
Then all cubes can be represented by a 3D array such that the cube with its closest edge to origin at ( a*n,  b*n, c*n ) is represented by index (a, b , c) in this 3d array.
And the value stored at that index is number of points inside that cube.
Here is pseudo code

```
//Pseudo code
int [N/n][N/n][N/n] arrayWithCountOfPointsInsideCubes;

void function countPointsForCubes(double point_x, point_y, point_z)
{ 
  arrayWithCountOfPointsInsideCubes[pint_x/n][point_y/n][point_z/n]++;
}
```